# AS3: syntax to do something when movieclip is on a specific frame

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax, frames

I have a character and an object. the object has multiple frames. I want to write code where the player interacts with the object, something different will happen if it's not in frame 1. Is there a way to compare the frame number in as3? If so what does it look like?

```
if mcobject.framenum != 1 then x

else y
```

Comment: [Why does no one bother to read the documentation?](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame)

Comment: I looked through documentation but couldn't find it, was looking under frames and not movieclip... thank you for finding it for me.

Answer (score 0):

mcobject.currentFrame
Answer in the documentation under movieclip - credit to DodgerThud for not being an idiot and knowing where to look